# Electron: Unable to open X display - ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(1400) - The futex facility returned an unexpected error code

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

I've been trying to run this code that brings up an electron GUI and takes input from the user. I I've used the following commands to run this project in VSCode powershell terminal:

`npm install`

`npm start`

I get the following error messages in the terminal afterwards:

[Error Message 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGIjN.png)

[Error Message 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yf8Lx.png)

[Error Message 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wyta.png)

I've already checked that I have the most updated packages for nodejs, npm, electron, electron-packager and electron-builder. You can see the last three in my package.json file under the devDependencies.

[Package.json dev dependencies and scripts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFJVF.png)

I don't really understand what the error is saying here. From the googling I've done, it seems like this happens on WSL when you're trying to launch an electron application but I'm working off of my local machine on Windows, so I wouldn't think that a GUI should throw an error.

I can run main.js by using `electron.cmd main.js` but this just brings up the GUI splash from electron but the code itself doesn't seem to be executing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The answer in my case was switching to use Yarn instead of npm. Clearing the node modules folder and running yarn install and running election ./app from the main project folder.